# Message port closed before a response was received despite return true

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm sending a message from my popup to background which when receives calls an external API and upon response from that api I'm sending a message back to pop up.

Popout

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        message: "submit",
        payload: {
            transactions: usersTxs,
        }
        }, (response) => { ... do other stuff }
```

background

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.message === 'submit'){
         fetch('https://example.com/api/submit'})
           .then((res) => {
                 sendResponse({ message: true })
                return true
            })
    }
```

However despite setting return true I'm still getting the following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're returning true at the wrong time - in the asynchronous handler that will execute later. Move your return statement:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.message === 'submit') {
         fetch('https://example.com/api/submit'})
             .then((res) => {
                 sendResponse({ message: true })
             })
         return true
    }
```