# Chrome extension React - Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension where I have to make a call in the background service worker and send the response back to the popup window, per manifest below.

```
    {
        "background": { 
            "service_worker": "background.bundle.js" 
        },
        "action": {
            "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },
    }
```

Here is where I make the request in the popup (using React), where I send the message `checkCredential` and expect a callback.

```
        const Login = ({
            loggedIn,
            onLogin,
        }) => {
            const [ticketKey, setTicketKey] = useState('FASDF');
            const [password, setPassword] = useState(
                'dafdhfdss'
            );

            const checkCredential = async () => {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "checkCredential", ticketKey, password}, async (response) => {
                    if (response.success) {
                        onLogin();
                    } else {
                        window.alert('Something wrong with the project key or personal token.');
                    }
                });
            };

            return (
                <>
                    <button type="button" onClick={checkCredential}>
                        Get fetch
                    </button>
                </>
            );
        };
```

Here is the `background.bundle.js` where I make the fetch and should return a resolved response via `sendResponse`.

```
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (
            request,
            sender,
            sendResponse
        ) {
            if (request.action === "checkCredential") {
                
                fetchData(request.ticketKey, request.password)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    }) 
                    .then(data => {
                        sendResponse({data: data, success: true})
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        sendResponse({data: error, success: false})
                    });

                    return true;
            }
            // Below may not be necessary, but for sake of completion
            else if (request.name === 'startRecording') {
                    startRecording();
                    return true; 
            }
            return true; 
        });

        function fetchData(ticketKey, password) {
            return fetch(`https://jira.ensemble.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/${ticketKey}/issuetypes`, {
                headers: {
                    'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${password}`,
                },
                method: 'GET',
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Fetch error:', error);
                throw error;
            });
        }
```

But when I run the code, the `sendMessage` callback in `popup` gets called even before the response is being resolved in `background.bundle.js`, and I get the following error:

> ```
> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'success')
>     at chrome-extension://ikomkadlip8njscndsbbhaphkkogabo/popup.bundle.js:43:122776
> popup.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
> ```

I followed the [other stack overflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73867123/message-port-closed-before-a-response-was-received-despite-return-true) of adding `return true;` statement, but still no avail.

Does anyone know what I may be missing, or have a working example I can reference?

Thanks,